# site works in firefox but no other browsers, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

should do this:

a progress bar appears, followed by thunbnails.. if it' working.

[image: should look like this]

Can someone please simply explain to me what i have written wrong in my markup?
I don't understand what might be the issue here so I am asking here,

My site: http://env-3884279.jelastic.servint.net/bot2/

if the 0% does not appear, it's working incorrectly,

refuses to run in any other browser except firefox. why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>capri</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->

    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

  </head>
  <body class="container" style="background-color: white; color: #333; font-family: 'Segoe UI';">

      <br /><br />

      <div>  
          <div id="status" class="pull-left"></div>
          <div id="total" class="pull-right bg-success table-bordered" style="padding: 6px;">0 Movies Processed.</div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>

          <br />
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">        
          </div>
      </div>

      <br />
      <div class="clearfix"></div>

      <div class="row-fluid" id="pagelist" style="border-top: solid whitesmoke 4px;">          
      </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

     <script>
         var processed = 0;
         function ScanPage(pagenum, callback) {

             $("#status").html("Please Wait... ");
             $('.progress-bar').hide();
             $('.progress-bar').css('width', 0 + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', 0).html(0 + '%');

             $.ajax({
                 url: "movies/merdb/scanpage.php?token=" + Math.random() + "&p=" + pagenum,
                 cache: false,
                 async: true,
                 type: "GET"
             }).done(function (html) {
                 var done = 0;
                 var json = JSON.parse(html);
                 var count = Object.keys(json).length;

                 $('.progress-bar').show();

                 $.each(json, function (iter) {
                     $.ajax({
                         url: "movies/merdb/parsepageresults.php?token=" + Math.random() + "&match=" + json[iter],
                         cache: false,
                         async: false,
                         type: "GET"
                     }).done(function (response) {

                         if (response != undefined && response != "") {
                             $("#status").html("<i class=\"fa fa-spinner fa-spin\"></i> Page <span class=\"badge\" style=\"background-color: whitesmoke; font-size: 16px;color: black;\">" + pagenum + "</span> Processing " + (done + 1) + " of " + count);
                             $("#pagelist").append("<div style=\"padding: 5px;\" class=\"col-xs-2\"><img src=" + response + " width=\"150\" height=\"225\"></div>");

                             var vpercent = parseInt(done * 100 / count);
                             $('.progress-bar').css('width', vpercent + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', vpercent).html(vpercent + '%');
                         }


                         done++;

                         processed++;
                         $("#total").html(processed + " Movies Processed.");

                     });
                 });

                 $("#status").html("Scanning Page " + pagenum + " has completed. <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\" style=\"color: green\">&nbsp;</span>");

                 callback(pagenum + 1); 
               });
         }

         function Begin(index) {
             ScanPage(index, OnCompleted);
         }

         function OnCompleted(index)
         {
             $("#pagelist").html("");
             Begin(index);
         }


         Begin(1);



     </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i know it's something with the javascript...

Comment: Care to describe what the desired behavior is?  What the observed behavior is in which browsers?  What steps you've taken to debug the issue?  What the browser debug console shows?  Which particular piece of code has the problem?  These are all expected troubleshooting steps you should take BEFORE you post your problem here.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox have the same behavior for me. What should it looked like? Maybe add a Screenshot.

Comment: see edited post.. It should be doing things if its working correctly, you'll see thunbails ect

Comment: As you're using Firefox, I suggest installing the Firebug plugin. It'll let you see errors in the console when loading your page so you can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: i got it working now in other browsers, but now the base64 images won't work. again they work in firefox...

Answer (score 0):

Try to put all yours  script's `<script src="https://aja....`  that you have on top.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
$('.progress-bar').hide();
```

if you want to see the 0%

Also the base64 returned is not correct and chrome is trying to download from a url

you are getting

"data:jpg;base64,......"

when you should be getting

"data:image/jpg;base64,...."

Answer (score 0):

Your Ajax minified java script is not responding properly. Try to put both minified java script in head section of HTML. Try to download and save the minified code and run it through your machine so process will be little faster.